# Do Marvel Studios share the same Mode of Production as Marvel Comics?

Tags: production, marvel-cinematic-universe

I know Marvel Comics have a fairly notorious process of development, with Bullpen Bulletins outlining the methodology of the brain trust over the years.

It seems little has been published/revealed about whether Marvel Studios have adopted the same mode of production (in [the Beller sense of](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Beller) the word).

Considering the films adopting more and more of divergent cinema production policy, it would seem to make sense to adapt the successful transmedia approach the comics have enjoyed, and Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D (not to mention the announced Netflix ancillary series) would indicate they are perhaps executing a similar plan.

Has there ever been any affirmation of this policy, from either Kevin Feige or any other Marvel Studios Affiliate? Has the comparison between production methods ever been explicitly made, on an official basis?

Comment: Still trying to make any sense out of this question. But I guess as someone not acquaited with *Jonathan Beller*'s work, let aside the meaning of *"mode of production"*, nor how *Marvel Comics*' development process works, I'm not going to answer this anyway and will just infer that it's kind of a good/interesting question. ;-)

Comment: I still can't get it. Looks like a good question but didn't got it. .....blank.......

Comment: To dumb it down a little for all you non-aca-fans [;)] Marvel have a very specific way of producing the franchises of their comics, so they can overlap in certain issues, which the MCU also has done with the various solo films and *Avengers Assemble*. I'm trying to find out if there has been any acknowledgement that the films were produced in the same way. 'Mode of Production' is a long standing industry term for, quite simply, the business/financial model that is employed to make films: E.G, Star System, Crowd-funded, studio system etc. etc.But Marvel Comics have their own, distinct system.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Studios)

> Marvel Studios, LLC originally known as Marvel Films from 1993 to 1996, is an American television and motion picture studio based at the Walt Disney Studios in Burbank, California. The Studio is a subsidiary of Marvel Entertainment (the company is known for its comic books and, as of the 2000s, its film productions from Marvel Studios,) a wholly owned subsidiary of The Walt Disney Company. Being a part of the Disney conglomerate, Marvel Studios works in conjunction with The Walt Disney Studios, another Disney unit, for distribution and marketing.

Per an interview with MTV Splash Page, Kevin Feige states that they understand that their audience is mixed between comic and action movie fans so they intentionally leave their movies "lobbing something in at the last moment to get the audience buzzing."

As for transmedial, it seems from the article that Marvel Studios relies on the audience driving the conversation. So in terms of Jonathan Beller's theory, it seems that Marvel creates questions for the audience to ask, answer, or discuss.

Comment: While I'm not entirely sure what it is exactly the OP wants to hear, I have strong guess he's at least read Wikipedia. The question seems more like their (Marvel Studios') way of operation and their way of procuding movies (whatever that really means). But it's at least a good start.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I'm looking for evidence of the way they plan and execute movies, their long term strategy outlines and whether they use transmedial deployment (and in what way) to establish brand continuity within convergence cinema. If that makes sense to anyone, please have a crack at it,*if it doesn't, nevermind!* it's not for you! ;-)

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional *"... If that makes sense to anyone"* - In fact that indeed makes sense and would be worth adding into the question, giving it a bit more substance, I think.